# Architecture/Design challenge: Consuming Social Media APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, architecture, soa, saas

We have been developing social media based Rails application which digs data of various services like twitter, facebook, linkedin and many more.
We are facing a serious performance issue to consume these services.

For example,
We are accessing Twitter user_timeline to prepare some statistics. 
As twitter has imposed [limitation on number of tweets can be fetched](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/276), we have to use pagination to fetch all tweets which results in multiple API calls and blocking IO.
Hence the user has to wait for many seconds which would not be acceptable UX.

We are new to Ruby/Rails and need suggestions to architect/design consuming such API(Facebook, LinkedIn) rightly. Please help us.

**Update**
We have been exploring ruby(delayed_job, eventmachine) and non-ruby(node.js) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Normally In rails world, login running processes such as you explained above are done through background services.

background services are like threads in Java. you the workflow would be

1. user comes to the web page
2. user clicks view tweets button (which will trigger the extraction of
   the data via twitter api)
3. tweet extraction is started as a background process
4. page will load without waiting until the api extraction is finished

and there are several background process gems [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), or [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/)

Comment: We have used delayed_job for sending email. The social APIs requires OAuth. Would it work well with delayed_job?

Comment: yes, coz delayed_job will run any process in background, whether its a mail sending or api processing. I personally have used delayed_job for some txt file generation process :)